# Android Wear and scope

Tags: discussion, scope

So, Google has announced **[Android Wear](http://developer.android.com/wear/index.html)** this week.

For those who don't know/don't have the time to read: it is a *smartwatch* but this one should be compatible with **ALL** Android powered phone and is simply a *shortcut* for notifications/events from your phone (it is paired trough an application downloaded from the Play Store). Having a Android Wear without a (Android?) phone to pair with is useless.

So, when it will be released, will we accept questions about Android Wear on this Stack Exchange?

Comment: "Android Wear" is the name of the platform for using Android on wearable devices. The first such devices are watches, but there are certain to be other form factors in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why wouldn't we? We already accept questions about [samsung-galaxy-gear](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-gear), which is the same class of thing. In general, we have a lot of questions about using Android with certain peripherals, such as Bluetooth keyboards. Since Android Wear is essentially a Bluetooth peripheral that's **only** for Android devices, it seems even more on-topic.

Comment: +1 We also already accept questions on the [tag:Pebble] smartwatch (when paired with an Android device). The recent [Is Google Glass in scope](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/1667/) discussion also seems relevant